# How can a user join a group in Drupal Commons?

Tags: organic-groups, 7

I'm using [Drupal Commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons) (unfortunately 7.x-3.0-beta1).

In Drupal Commons, how can a user join a group?

Either my site has been customized out of all recognition or I simply can't see where a normal authenticated user goes to join a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In your Drupal admin area, go to "Administration → Structure → Content types → Group → Manage Display → Default" (`/admin/structure/types/manage/group/display`).
2. Set column "Format" for field "Group" to "OG subscribe link".

Your groups will now display a "Subscribe to Group" link on the groups' pages. This only applies for users who have the privilege to request membership to a specific group (which can be set in both the global OG permissions, and can be overwritten per group).

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from the Acquia folks, the join functionality has been renamed to "Follow" in Commons 3. So, if you go to the groups tab, the groups listed should have a Follow button with a megaphone icon that a user can click.

I'm guessing you're aware, but just in case you're not, there is a non-beta version of Commons 3 out now. I had tried out one of the betas and the Follow button was there at the time, but I'm not sure when it was added or if I had beta1 or a more recent beta.

Comment: Actually, no. Following and group membership are still separate concepts in Drupal Commons. "Follow" (the megaphone button) means you get notifications about updates in this group. "Membership" means you are listed as a member / contributor, and in the case of private groups it's precondition to seeing the group content at all.